# i would like to install the npm in a Laravel project but it brings me this error

Tags: php, laravel

```
npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm install
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that **npm is not installed** on your machine:

Quote from https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm  :

> **npm is installed with Node.js**
>
> npm is distributed with Node.js - **which means that when you download Node.js, you automatically get npm installed on your computer.**

Get the `node.js` download from https://nodejs.org/en/